# Crud operation using jtable and jquery plugin

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I  want to make a simple CRUD operation using jsp, servlet and database.I want to pass action from jsp to servlet to insert,update,delete data from database table.My code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {


        actions: {
            listAction: 'CRUDController?action=list'
            deleteAction: 'CRUDController?action=delete'
            updateAction: 'CRUDController?action=update'
            createAction: 'CRUDController?action= create'
        },
```

I want to pass the action string to CRUDController servlet and receive it using if else condition such as

```
    if (action.equals("list")) {
      Show employeelist}
else if (action.equals("update")) {
      edit employeelist}
else if (action.equals("create")) {
     insert data into employeelist}
```

But action is not passing to servlet and edit,delete,insert operation is not working.If i could pass the action strings i would've made the edit,delete,insert operation work. What should i do?
I got the idea from here http://www.programming-free.com/2013/08/ajax-based-crud-operations-in-java-web.html
http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/ajax-based-crud-operations-in-jsp-and-servlet-using-jtable-jquery-plug-in/

But my action is not passing to the servlet

Comment: How are you actually invoking the servlet from JavaScript/HTML?

Comment: using the url of the servlet "CRUDController" i used the CRUDcontroller to receive the action parameter from jsp page only . here is my code http://pastebin.com/HY2rWCEp

Answer (score 0):

Use `jquery` Ajax plugin like :

[Jquery Ajax example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)
[Web application Jquery Ajax](http://www.journaldev.com/4742/jquery-ajax-servlet-jsp-web-application-integration-example-tutorial)

Hope it will help you to call `Servlet` using `Jquery` `Ajax`

Comment: i wanted to do like  this example but it is not working http://www.programming-free.com/2013/08/ajax-based-crud-operations-in-java-web.html